# mongoose update not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I checked many questions on stackoverflow and modified this  simple query thats not working I don't know why...

```
 router.get('/users/:username/suspend', function(req, res){
        var username = req.params.username;
        User.findByUsername(username, function(err, user){
            console.log(user);
            user.suspended = true;
            user.save(function(err, u){
                res.redirect('ok');
            });

        });

});
```

I tried many ways like using model.update with upsert true and false....
Also its console.log is giving right username in callback.... but there is no change in database...

Comment: What does your `User` schema look like?

Comment: you can't set user.suspended = true that way I think.

Comment: @lyjackal thanks for pointing out. Working after i added suspended field to schema. but it should also work without adding to schema...

Comment: yeah, I don't think mongoose pays any attention to fields not in the schema, I'm not sure if it will retrieve them, but I'm pretty sure it will never update them.

Comment: .save do alot of validation that way, it make delta based on current and what on schema and update partially with $set, instead of full record like native mongodb does.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 3.x version of mongoose before a .save can be used to update a model you need to mark the field as modified on the model.

```
 router.get('/users/:username/suspend', function(req, res){
    var username = req.params.username;
    User.findByUsername(username, function(err, user){
        console.log(user);
        user.suspended = true;
        user.markModified('suspended');
        user.save(function(err, u){
            res.redirect('ok');
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to try is

```
user.set('suspended', true);
```

Comment: why you posted two separate answers, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30420250/edit) your first answer